# Multicolumn longpage spread in two over the same page

Tags: positioning, longtable

is my first day using Latex and i feel kinda lost.
I have a 4 column data (pretty long,like 200 rows, so i guess i need to use longpage) but the columns are very thin, so i would like to fit the same table but spread in two over the same page. Idk if i explained myself properly but mine is like this:

[image]

And i would like to make it like this (forget esthetical differences i only mean placement)

[image]

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{$\theta$ [rad]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{$V$ [V]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{$\theta_\sigma$ [rad]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{$\theta_V$}}\\ \hline 
tons of data
\end{longtable}
```

This is the primitive code i am using.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: You cxould just manually break it into two tabulars and place them side by side (\centering and \hfil).